# I have a Java exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java

Edit:
I was forgot to change the start class to the client package in Eclipse!

This is odd, it works fine in eclipse, then I export it and it gives me a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` .

The pastebin of Start.java

http://pastebin.com/KxfApWKb

The dump:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "gudenau.no-ip.org"

        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.gudenau.ChatServer.Start.main(Start.java:141)
```

I don't get why it works in eclipse but not with a batch file.

The code I use for the socket is

```
socket = new Socket("gudenau.no-ip.org", 45678);
```

I will change this to not be static later.

```
    try {
        socket = new Socket("gudenau.no-ip.org", 45678);

        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-3);
    }
```

Edit the code around 141:

```
@Override
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: can you show us the source code in question?

Comment: Shure:      try {
   socket = new Socket("gudenau.no-ip.org", 45678);

   out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     socket.getInputStream()));
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.exit(-1);
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.exit(-2);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.exit(-3);
  }

Comment: Your code is OK. Are you sure you don't have a firewall on which you might have authorized Eclipse ?

Comment: I am pretty sure, it is a java problem is it not.

Comment: Are you calling Integer.parseInt() or any other method near line 141 in your code ? It would be better if you place [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: No, from eclipse, I have put code close to 141 in my post. 141 is the first } in the last code block.

Comment: *I don't get why it works in eclipse but not with a batch file*, from batch file how are you executing it? Have you created any jar ? If yes recreate your jar and then try again

Comment: I have created a few jars, the code in the script is:
java -jar Client.jar
pause

Comment: `NumberFormatException` is not a 'Socket exception'. Your code doesn't agree with your stack trace. Not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the start class in the eclipse jar exporter! Oops!

Answer (score 1):

The code you added for line 141 doesn't seem to be correct (I could be wrong). The error is coming from a class called Start (line 141). I am guessing you are trying to create an Integer there, but from a String that does not parse into an Integer.

You may want to add a debug point at that method (or some System.outs) to see what you are actually trying to convert to an Integer.

Update: you are looking at the wrong package, you need com.gudenau.ChatServer, not com.gudenau.ChatCleint.

Comment: Update after reading your pastebin. The class you added in there has a package of "com.gudenau.ChatCleint", you need to look at the class with the package of "com.gudenau.ChatServer".

Comment: But the problem is in the cleint... How does that help?

Comment: @gudenau - the exception is thrown from `com.gudenau.ChatServer.Start.main()` at line 141

Comment: Oh, I think I know how to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you show indicates that the exception is from line 141 of `Start.main()`, which directly instantiates an `Integer` object.  Since the `Socket` constructor is taking a primitive `int`, this cannot be the actual problem.  Please update your post with the code surrounding line 141 of `Start.main()` for a better answer